# Is it safe to use DNSCrypt along side TorBrowser Bundle?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac, dns, information-leaks

I came across a different question where an [answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/2017/tor-browser-bundle-has-stopped-working-mac/2187#2187) mentioned DNSCrypt might cause issues with TBB (I don't have enough reputation to comment there and didn't what to hijack that question so I'm starting a new one here.)

I kind of presumed that TBB was self contained and handled all its DNS requests itself. So I presumed that it was bypassing DNSCrypt. This thread on [Tor](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-does-tor-route-dns-requests/26#26) (not TorBroswer, which is what I'm concerned with) seems to suggests that might be correct.

I'm on OS X 10.8.5 and I use the DNSCrypt GUI 0.19. But I'm sure the same principles apply to all OSes and non-GUI DNScrypt.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out whether DNS requests are resolved by TBB or DNScrypt here:
http://ipleak.net/
(DNS detection only works with Javascript enabled)

Keep in mind that the DNScrypt GUI versions made by OpenDNS are highly outdated.
Newer versions of DNScrypt are available on dnscrypt.org
They are also configurable to use DNS servers other than OpenDNS's.

Answer (score 0):

DNS resolves are done on the exit node side. So there are no DNS leaks when you use TBB. DNScrypt encrypts the dns request, true, but provides no anonymity at all.