# On my Imac, the connection has timed out

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac

I use a Imac used to have a windows PC and Tor worked perfectly on it.

However, on my Imac I have changed the proxy setting to 172.0.0.1 and port 9150 but it is still saying the connection has timed out?

It loads the first page saying you are now connected but everything on that does not work?

Comment: If you have Sophos installed, [this has been already answered](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/2088/1041).

Comment: The IP setting should be 127.0.0.1, not 172.0.0.1.. Or is it a typo?

Comment: This question seems abandoned, thus I'll close it. If you have further information, please [edit](https://tor.stackexchange.com/posts/3726/edit) the question and it can be reopened.